# Centrally manage thumbs.db for multiple clients on a CIFS share

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, photos, thumbs.db

I have a multimedia archive viewable read-only by multiple Windows 7 clients. Each time the clients browse the directory in Windows Explorer, the thumbnails are re-created. They're useful, but they take 10s of minutes on directories with 1000s of photographs and videos. The recreation process also adds load to the file server.

To solve this, I would like to maintain thumbs.db in each media directory on the Linux machine hosting the shares.

Is it possible, using Linux, to create a thumbs.db that can be consumed by all clients? If not, are there problems with creating thumbs.db on one of the clients and copying it to the share?